# Calling a function not show anything

Tags: vue.js

have a vue file, i call a function but not show nothing, when i call the same function in a button and a console log, the result is correct.

```
     <div v-if="this.aux==1" >
     <a href="/" class="rutan">Gama materiales</a><a href="/productos" class="rutan">/Productos/</a><a class="ruta" id="cedi1">{{this.sucursal()}}</a>
     <a id="cedi" class="rutan" v-if="this.id_padre!=0" v-once v-bind:href="'/productos?'+'regreso='+0+'&suc='+this.url">{{this.sucursal()}}</a>
   <a class="ruta" v-if="this.id_padre!=0" >/{{this.subcategoria()}}</a> <--- this is the function
    
     </div>
```

i tried remove the v-if and same, this is the function

```
    subcategoria(){
let me=this;
axios
.get("/catalogo/subcategoria/"+this.id_padre)
    .then((response) => {
                this.allData = response.data;
               
                console.log('datos', this.allData[0].nombre);
               
                
          });
          return this.allData[0].nombre;
    },
```

this are the result of console.log

[The last text "datos cemento" is the result of the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fW7a7.png)

and this is the result

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q15wy.png)

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please make an effort in terms of formatting and trying to explain your issue a bit better. I submitted an edit to your code snippet and also removed all the `this` since they are totally useless in the template. Try to use ESlint + prettier to have an easier life ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```html
<a @click="subcategoria">click me</a>
```

But you should know that doing that kind of thing is not recommended. A link is to **move** to a page. A `button` is used to make actions.